# jQuery apply class underneath

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have some css like so

```
#menu li
{
   color:#336633;
}
.hover
{
   color:#ffffff;
   background-color:#336633;
}
```

I am using jQuery's hover like so
on hover: addClass('hover');
on out: removeClass('hover');

This changes the background color but not the font color. I suspect this is because the class is being applied first and then the default li behavior gets applied? Is there an easy way to make this work? I don't want to use a class for default li behavior, then remove it, apply hover and reapply default.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the order in which these statements appear in your CSS?
For the above code to work, .hover class MUST appear after the #menu li definition.

Alternatively, you can add !important to color property.

```
.hover
{
   color:#ffffff !important;
   background-color:#336633;
}
```

Comment: BTW, I think this is because id selectors have higher preference than the class selectors. If you had styled your LI using class, then you won't need !important.

Comment: Joel, IE6 definitely supports !important declaration. Link: http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/104195

Comment: Nice link. I guess I was wrong, it's just the implementation that is sketchy. I've always avoided the use of !important because I consider it a hack.

Comment: I don't think the bug is with !important. The problem is how IE interprets if you specify rule for same property multiple times. If you do that, then it's a hack, otherwise !important works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your li selector is more specific than your class selector.

Try:

```
#menu li
{
   color:#336633;
}
#menu li.hover
{
   color:#ffffff;
   background-color:#336633;
}
```

Comment: I like your solution better. +1.